# String syntacs is wrong

Tags: java, string, text

Can someone tell me what's wrong about this `String`:

```
String name = bundle.getString("textViewName");

String smsBody = "Hello!" +name "have gone missing.";
```

In the second line I get an error. But this works:

```
String name = bundle.getString("textViewName");

String smsBody = "Hello!" + name;
```

I need more text after I print the name. Does someone know how?

Comment: `String smsBody = "Hello!" +name + "have gone missing.";` please, notice the *second* plus `+`

Comment: The programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a + after name.

```
String smsBody = "Hello!" + name + "have gone missing.";
```